# Custom Cell textfield non editable

Tags: ios, textfield

I have a custom cell where there are two textfields. I have list of objects where I populate them on each cell. Textfields could be editable as a default, however I would like to know how I could able to make the first row first textfield noneditable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCell *cell = (MyCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
    cell.endabled = YES;
    if(indexPath.section==0 && indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.customTextField.enabled = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: There is a typo in the `cell.endabled--> cell.enabled`

Answer (score 1):

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check for the `indexPath` being section 0 and row 0. if so set the `textField`s `enabled` property to `NO` / `false`.